# How to change the opacity of multiple polygon of one layer at a time?

Tags: qgis, polygon, transparency-opacity, multiple

I'm using QGIS 3.22.
I have a shapefile with 290 polygons and wanted to change the opacity of 205 polygons(selected) at a time. How is it possible?

Comment: Select "Project -> Properties -> Commom -> Selection Color" and set color opacity

Answer (score 4):

Individual polygon opacity can be set via its color `alpha` parameter. By hand, it is the slider below the color picker.

[image]

To affect several polygons at once, without creating different styles, you can create a new column (named `alpha` for simplicity) of type integer, with values between 0 (fully transparent) and 255 (fully opaque). Set the value of your selected polygons, then revert the selection and set the value of the remaining polygons.

Modify your style(s) color by clicking on the little `epsilon` icon beside the color, and enter the following expression:

```
set_color_part(@symbol_color, 'alpha', alpha)
```

It instruct to set the `alpha` value of the color, using the column named `alpha`, and to keep the current symbol color.

In the example below, we have a categorized style and the central island has a different opacity than any other polygons. See how the line layer content, located below, is/isn't visible.

[image]

Comment: Bull's eye @JGH, as your icon. Thanks a lot. You understood the problem and answer me exactly what I need. Peace :)